# Why aren't some launchers compatible with some devices?

Tags: launcher, google-now, compatibility

I was reading the reviews of the Google Now Launcher where they have stated that after installing the launcher the device has audio issues.

[image: Google now launcher reviews with audio issues on some device.]

I did not understand how can a launcher affect the hardware output of a device because as far as I understand the launcher only gives a pure vanilla experience.

Is there a possibility that a launcher like Google Now Launcher is not compatible with some devices? (Even thought it meets the requirements of the launcher)

Comment: It seems both apps mentioned in the review are related to audio input (Shazam can identify a music based from mic, and Skype is a VoIP app). I can only guess that it might be related to Google Now's "Always listening" feature. However, I didn't get that issue on Nexus 4/5, and without more info, it's kind of hard to know the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

The launcher can't modify device audio input itself.

There always is a possibility for something to not work even when it's marked as compatible (like HTC Explorer with Snapchat). It should work but it doesn't.